# Create dynamic function in python?

Tags: python

I got NameError for calling test_gobject, but the funny thing is I never called this function name. I called **test_gobjectpy()**
Can you explain it to me why Python decide to call the wrong function name (see error output)

Maybe it has some problems because I have a string with the same name as function?!

file name **test_dyn_fun.py**

```
second_path = ['test_gobject.py', 'st1.py', 'test_show_desktop.py', 'download_img.py', 'test_dump.py']
print("second_path", second_path)
print()
for i in second_path:
    #func = create_dyn_func(i)
    tmp = i.replace(".", "")  #rm dot for function name
    print("tmp =", tmp)
    exec(f"def {tmp}(): print({i})")
print()
print(dir(test_gobjectpy))
print()
print(locals())
test_gobjectpy()
```

Error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/manta/Coding/test_dyn_fun.py", line 13, in <module>
    test_gobjectpy()
  File "<string>", line 1, in test_gobjectpy
NameError: name 'test_gobject' is not defined
```

Comment: What do you think the function body of `test_gobjectpy` looks like?

Comment: @user2357112 I think there is no body it's just a print statement

Comment: That `print` call is the body. What do you think that `print` call looks like?

Comment: @user2357112 I don't understand what you mean with that?

Comment: Before you call `exec`, try *printing* the code you're about to execute. See what you're actually doing. (Also, you really need to learn what a function body is.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop you create functions, the first one created is effectively created like this:

```
i = 'test_gobject.py' 
tmp = 'test_gobjectpy'
exec(f"def {tmp}(): print({i})")
```

So, it's as if you ran:

```
exec("def test_gobjectpy(): print(test_gobject.py)")
```

For Python to print `test_gobject.py`, it tries to access an object called `test_gobject` and its attribute `.py`.

That's what is causing the error. The fact that `test_gobject.py` looks like a filename to you doesn't matter, it's just names of variables to Python, the way you wrote it.

What would you expect to happen if you called this function?

```
def test_gobjectpy():
    print(test_gobject.py)
```

More in general, as a beginning programmer, it's generally best to stay away from stuff like `exec()` and `eval()`. It's very common for new Python programmers to think they need this, or that it somehow solves a problem they have, but it's generally the worst solution to the problem and rarely actually a good solution at all. (not never, just rarely)

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you. My error isn't my function name like a thought, it's the object that I passed to the function body because the object is not known?